# this in builder cannot be applied

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chat app using firebase. I am trying to notify the user when receive a new message.  My problem is with `this`.  I am getting an error saying that `builder(content.context) in builder cannot be applied to (anonymous com......)`

Here is my code:

```
reference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Map map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
        String message = map.get("message").toString();
        String userName = map.get("user").toString();
//If i am the sender
        if(userName.equals(UserDetails.username)){
            addMessageBox("You:-\n" + message, 1);
        }
        else {
//if somebody else send a message
                addMessageBox(UserDetails.chatWith + ":-\n" + message, 2);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.hello)
                            .setContentTitle("My notification")
                            .setContentText("Hello World!");



        }
    }
```

Any tips?

**Edit**

as mentioned in the answer below
the problem is that this refers to the ChildEventListener and not the activity so i had to create a method out side the ChildEventListener so "this" can refer to the activity it self and called the it where i want it to be

Comment: Use `MainActivity.this`, or whatever name your Activity is

Comment: error is gone but not receiving any notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to `new ChildEventListener()`.

You need a Context, which would be an Activity, for example.

So you can either use `YourActivity.this`, or

```
final Context context = this;
reference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
   ...
```

and use `context` within the event listener

Comment: error is gone but am not receiving any notification.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. Your question was only about getting the code to compile

Comment: You did only create a builder. Nothing in your question is going to display a notification

Comment: oh srry i didnt show the whole code, i created an object called startNotification out side the ChildEventListener and called it inside and it worked and now this refers to the activity it self. thanks alot